# It is not possible to make nested migrations to Prisma

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create my first API on nets.js/prisma/postgresql
But I had difficulties describing the models in the prisma
I want that on request https://my-api/seasons the server gave a response of the form:

```
[
  {
    "Season1": {
      "name": "Season 1",
      "series": {
        "seria1": {
          "title": "text 1 1",
          "url": "url 1 1",
          "date": "date 1 1"
        },
        "seria2": {
          "title": "text 1 2",
          "url": "url 1 2",
          "date": "date 1 2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Season2": {
      "name": "Season 2",
      "series": {
        "seria1": {
          "title": "text 2 1",
          "url": "url 2 1",
          "date": "date 2 1"
        },
        "seria2": {
          "title": "text 2 2",
          "url": "url 2 2",
          "date": "date 2 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

To make it clearer and clearer:

[json data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1hoi.png)

[json data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAnc4.png)

This is a simplified kind of migration that doesn't work for me
How can I make the same level of nesting using Prisma migration as I described above?

```
model Seasons {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     Season @relation(fields: [seasonId], references: [id])
  seasonId Int
}

model Season {
  id      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String    @db.VarChar(40)
  Seasons Seasons[]
}
```

Comment: "Migration" usually refers to the concept of database migrations. I think, you are looking for a relation query: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries

Comment: @some-user

 I kind of did what you had in mind, but the result still didn't work out

Comment: Please share what you did and what the result was and how this did not match your expectation...

Comment: @some-user I linked Seasons with Season, even visually saw the result through Prisma Studio, but when I request the server ../seasons, I do not get a list of my seasons

Comment: Please post your query.